# sudo journalctl -f - Why i dont see latest news?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

today i have 9 november - but logs communicats show me only info from 8 november (in polish november=listopad --> lis ) and i don't understand why and how i can repeired this ... any tips?

```
$ sudo journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Mon 2021-11-08 19:07:26 CET. --
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Journal Service.
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd-journald[1807]: Journal started
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd-journald[1807]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/daa6352d762b4c09814962c8fdbfc6fb) is 8.0M, max 191.3M, 183.3M free.
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi sudo[1804]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
lis 08 19:59:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
lis 08 20:00:32 raspberrypi sudo[1811]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi/PDF ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -f
lis 08 20:00:32 raspberrypi sudo[1811]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
lis 08 20:02:02 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[491]: Connections: connected: 192.168.1.116::53170 (TCP)
lis 08 20:02:15 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[491]: session started: user pi permissions f
lis 08 20:02:15 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[491]: Connections: authenticated: 192.168.1.116::53170 (TCP), as pi (f permissions)
lis 08 20:02:15 raspberrypi colord[508]: failed to get session [pid 408]: Brak danych
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i understand - my raspberry pi wasn't synchronized time. - It has date with one day before real date

I set actual date with command 'sudo date -s 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Comment: If you are connected to the internet there should be an NTP service (`systemd-timesyncd`) running which keeps the time synchronized the same way your phone, other computers, etc. do.  You could check this with `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`).